# Howto make this Windows-Service-Scenario as comely as possible

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-3.5, windows-services

I have following scenario:
[alt text http://static.zooomr.com/images/7579022_e64808b855_o.png](http://static.zooomr.com/images/7579022_e64808b855_o.png)
We have a WebService which poses as a search-engine, used by WebApps
But as we all know on 32bit systems and IIS6: 800Mb is the max. alloc-mem for a webapp...

Now I had the following idea, as we are exceeding this limitation:
[alt text http://static.zooomr.com/images/7579028_c423e52b46_o.png](http://static.zooomr.com/images/7579028_c423e52b46_o.png)
Let the WCF communicate with a Windows Service, which isn't affected by this constraint!

But this brings me to some questions:
How can I communicate with a Windows Service as I would communicate as a client with the WCF (having methods with parameters, getting objects as return value, etc...).

After thinking about this a bit, [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687608/calling-windows-service-from-a-web-service/688357#688357) came up to me.
But I'm not familiar with this scenario.

Do some of you know some good resource, where I can get the knowledge to realize this scenario (maybe with demo-apps)?
Or does someone maybe have a better idea of how realize this scenario even more comely?

This scenario wil be completely done with C# 3.0 and .NET 3.5(SP1)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely use WCF as the communication layer between the web-app and the service.  You can host a [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) in your windows service, and serve up any type of WCF endpoint.

A common pattern I've seen is to connect a web layer and service layer using MSMQ (Net MSMQ binding), so that you have disconnected calls, and some buffering to allow for load tolerance.  If you don't need the buffering, you can use any other type of binding (Net TCP or even HTTP, although sometimes it tricky to get HTTP setup correctly outside of IIS).

Here's a good tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx